# How can I select multiple files in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to write a extension to do a function like this:

1. select two or more files
2. right click and choose command something like `merge files` in `explore/context`
3. open a dialog to save result

I find that it seems `vscode` don't has an API to select files in `explore`. **So how can I do `select multiple files`?**

And also according to [extension-points](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points), I find all `RawContextKey` [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/search?p=1&q=RawContextKey&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93), I do not find a condition meet my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode 1.20 introduced [multi select in explorer window](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_multi-select-in-the-explorer). In documentation I didn't find `when` clause that you may use in order to find out whether 2 files are selected or only one, but in source code I've found those contexts:

```
const RawWorkbenchListFocusContextKey = new RawContextKey<boolean>('listFocus', true);
export const WorkbenchListSupportsMultiSelectContextKey = new RawContextKey<boolean>('listSupportsMultiselect', true);
export const WorkbenchListFocusContextKey = ContextKeyExpr.and(RawWorkbenchListFocusContextKey, ContextKeyExpr.not(InputFocusedContextKey));
export const WorkbenchListDoubleSelection = new RawContextKey<boolean>('listDoubleSelection', false);
export const WorkbenchListMultiSelection = new RawContextKey<boolean>('listMultiSelection', false);
```

Specifically, `WorkbenchListDoubleSelection` is used for `Compare selected` command in context menu when you select 2 files.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/9e6944d0edf2e787df110c9f444280e7256d4149/src/vs/workbench/parts/files/electron-browser/fileActions.contribution.ts#L375-L379

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/aa580cae2dc92501df8e1342b72b9dc5c2d8c58f/src/vs/platform/list/browser/listService.ts#L90-L94

Answer (score 0):

VSCode recently added ability to allow multi selection in custom views. To allow multi select in the custom view you should specify second parameter `TreeViewOptions<T>` in `window.createTreeView` function call and set it's property `canSelectMany` to true.
Sample usage will look like this:

```
window.createTreeView(/*YOUR_VIEW_NAME*/, {
    treeDataProvider: /*YOUR_TREE_DATA_PROVIDER*/,
    canSelectMany: true // enables multi selection
});
```